# Is it possible to make Python interpret a script line by line and generate output as if from an interactive shell?

Tags: python, shell, python-interactive

Considering the following interactive shell session.

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1+1
2
>>> 2+5
7
>>> "foo"
'foo'
>>>
```

Observe how, after every line, the interpreter will echo the result to the console.

If I put those same three commands into a script `Foo.py` **without print statements**, there will be no output generated.

Is there a way to force the Python interpreter to generate the **same output** as it would under interactive mode *without modifying the code to manually insert print statements*?

Comment: To be clear: you want to print out the return value of every single statement/block in your script.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, I want to not only print it, I want it printed exactly as it would be in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: How about a shell script that just does `python -c "print repr(line)"` for each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import code
console = code.InteractiveConsole()
prompt = '>>>'
source = '''
1 + 1
2+5
"foo"
x = 1
x
y = (2+
     3)
y + x     
'''.splitlines()
for line in source:
    print('{p} {l}'.format(p=prompt, l=line.rstrip()))
    prompt = '...' if console.push(line) else '>>>'
```

yields

```
>>> 
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> 2+5
7
>>> "foo"
'foo'
>>> x = 1
>>> x
1
>>> y = (2+
...      3)
>>> y + x
6
```

Comment: This will do it! Thanks.